# Generation of random numbers from the multivariate normal distribution in spherical coordinates

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, algorithms

Can any one point me to a research article or post the actual algorithm to generate random numbers from the multivariate normal distribution in spherical coordinates?

I need both $N_p(0,I_p)$ , the standard multivariate normal case in spherical coordinates and $N_p(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma \neq I_p$

Comment: You need to explain first what you want to do. Are you looking to draw samples that are normal distributed in Euclidean x-y-z space and convert the result into spherical coordinates? Or are you interested in drawing samples from a normal distribution in r-phi-theta space? The two are fundamentally different and, in fact, the latter doesn't make much sense because phi and theta are periodic variables and so having a normal distribution in these variables makes not much sense because $p(\phi)$ must equal $p(\phi+2\pi)$ but this is of course inconsistent with the normal distribution.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth , i think daek's method is what i need , but i'm not 100% sure yet 
http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/papers/mvncmp/mvncmp.html

Comment: THe problem is poorly posed. Do you need $N_p(0,I_p)$? Do you need $N_p(0,\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma \neq I_p$? Do you need $N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$?

Comment: I do not understand the emphasis on spherical coordinates. Is there anything the matter with generating a variable from $N(0,\Sigma)$ and converting it to spherical coordinates?

Comment: i need to test every possibility

Comment: Given that even the *input* to the $\mathcal{N}_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ problem is $O(p^2)$ and the [conversion from Cartesian to spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) is $O(p)$, the time needed for conversion is inconsequential except for small $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ERSSDBDcYOIC&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=generate%20random%20numbers%20from%20the%20multivariate%20normal%20distribution%20in%20spherical%20coordinates&source=bl&ots=hWWENS2Vst&sig=FZW65dk9z86ksEd9_RcB8_zIF1A&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=n-EfUKffFciB7AGo3oDgBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=generate%20random%20numbers%20from%20the%20multivariate%20normal%20distribution%20in%20spherical%20coordinates&f=false) has [this reference](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=ERSSDBDcYOIC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=Deak%201990%20random%20number&source=bl&ots=hWWENS2Wsp&sig=kVIaUfmUFh_le1VjX5eoTy4iYfY&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ei=_-EfUKbNA6LW6wHSyYDgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Deak%201990%20random%20number&f=false) to [this book](http://www.alibris.com/booksearch?qwork=10918703) here. Not exactly cheap, but I think it's the one you are looking for. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Given [how easy it is to generate the normal variates](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html), I would do just that, and then convert to the spherical coordinates directly.

If you need $N_p(0,I_p)$, where $p$ is the dimension, then in spherical coordinates, $r\sim \chi^2_p = \Gamma(p/2,1/2)$, and the angles are all independent of each other and the length, with uniform distribution on their respective ranges $[0,\pi)$ for the first one (the one that goes with the cosine only), $[0,2\pi)$ for the remaining ones. If $p$ is even, $p=2m$, you can generate $r_p = \sum_{k=1}^{m} (-\frac12) \ln U_k$, $U_k \sim \mbox{i.i.d. } U[0,1]$. If $p$ is odd, $p=2m+1$, then you need to add another square of a normal to this (see above how to generate them), $r_p = r_{p-1} + z^2$, $z\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: can you show the proof for $r\sim \chi^2_p = \Gamma(p/2,1/2)$ ?

Comment: also the link you posted is for the uni-variate Gaussian

Comment: Take a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution

Comment: @zen I know that but that doesn't answer my original question